# How can I maintain invisible solutions to exercises within an org-file?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

Running code within an Org file greatly simplifies writing. It's
possible to see the output and confirm everything works as expected.

```
** Exercises

Implement the following function.

#+BEGIN_SRC python
   ... exercise
   ... exercise
#+END_SRC
```

It would be even nicer to write the solutions to exercises
within the same document, and to run the solution to confirm all is
as expected—all without getting out of org-mode.

I can of course comment the solution in/out.

```
#+begin_comment
#+BEGIN_SRC python
   ... solution
   ... solution
#+END_SRC
#+end_comment
```

Might there be a way that doesn't require these unnecessary edits?

How can I maintain invisible solutions to exercises within an org-file?

Comment: The :ignore or :noexport tags works well in this situation. Just add it to the solution sub-heading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To easily comment/uncomment the solution, you can use `C-c ;` (`org-toggle-comment`) on the "Solution" headline. If you don't want the "Solution" headline to appear in the exported document, you add the `:ignore:` tag:

```
** Exercises

Implement the following function.

#+BEGIN_SRC python
   ... exercise
   ... exercise
#+END_SRC

*** Solution :ignore:
#+BEGIN_SRC python
   ... solution
   ... solution
#+END_SRC
```

To make `:ignore:` work you have to add some lines to your init. E.g.:

```el
(use-package org-contrib
  :config
  (require 'ox-extra)
  (ox-extras-activate '(ignore-headlines)))
```

Note that instead of `org-toggle-comment` You could also use the `:noexport:` tag:

```
*** Solution :noexport:
#+BEGIN_SRC python
   ... solution
   ... solution
#+END_SRC
```

Comment: Fantastic, but then it's even simpler. It's enough to write `*** COMMENT Solution`, and we hit two birds with one stone. The subsubsection will not appear in the export, and the code block can still be run as usual through C-c C-c, and then it's unnecessary to comment the solution out/in.

Comment: Also, it could then be possible to use the `:noexport:` tag on `*** Solution`. Personally I prefer the `*** COMMENT Solution` option, since there is a keybinding for it. I just mention `:noexport:` FYI. You can accept the solution if it solves your issue.

Comment: Right... `*** COMMENT Solution` and `*** Solution :noexport:` seem to be indeed wholly equivalent in this context. Feel free to blend all this into your answer so that future readers can more clearly access this Q&A as a reference, but I myself am content.

Comment: I just added the `:noexport:` option to the solution.